# References to .NET assemblies on server 2008

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, iis

I've recently just attempted to deploy a site (it's a web api project) I worked on a Win 2K8 server with IIS installed and the .NET 4.5 framework installed. i was surprised when it didn't work. It basically acted as if it had never heard of the MVC-style routing notion; because it was issuing a controller/action/id type request it didn't know to invoke the routing engine and map this to controller actions.

I eventually took the fairly extreme and silly approach of setting copylocal = true for *all* assemblies in the project, even the ones that I know must be in the GAC. Bin-deploying it this way works.

So....my question is this - how do I know which need to be copied local and which don't? I mean, I installed the .NET framework 4.5 on the server, and ultimately it seems as if the libraries involved should have been resolved because the .NET framework was installed? Of course the nuget packages all need to be copylocal=true, but within the set of MS standard libraries it seems as if the web site still doesn't find all of them.

Is there a rule I can follow that helps me understand which ones I need to copy locally?

Answer (score 0):

If ASP.NET MVC 4 is the first version you use, and you don't learn every aspects of the framework from a good enough book, I hope you spend some time to review related articles on the Internet to get better understanding,

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/BINDeployingASPNETMVC3WithRazorToAWindowsServerWithoutMVCInstalled.aspx

http://haacked.com/archive/2011/05/25/bin-deploying-asp-net-mvc-3.aspx/

ASP.NET MVC is not bundled in .NET Framework, so most of the binaries you refer to must be set as `copylocal=true`. This must be painful for beginners, but experienced users are already familiar with that.